# dialog inside of a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, jdialog, jinternalframe

I have a `JInternalFrame` and I need to get some Information from user (a `JFileChooser` & two `JTextfield`).
Using another JInternalFrame, application continues running and doesn't wait for input.
How can I open a `JDialog` as a internal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogs that are internal frames should be implemented using JInternalFrame (or JOptionPane) not JDialog

Comment: But by using JInternalFrame app. continues running and doesn't wait for input; and about JOptionPane, Can I have a JFileChooser and Custom JtextFields on it?

Comment: A `JOptionPane` can have a button to launch a file chooser, as well as multiple components.